# Python list unroll in a recursive function

Tags: python, recursion

The following is my python recursive function code:

```
char_list=[]
def xyz(sample_string):
    global char_list
    if sample_string!="":
        char_list.append(sample_string[0])
        xyz(sample_string[1:])
    # once sample_string == "", the function will start unrolling
    # While unrolling, I wanted to do certain operations on the char_list elements and other operations which includes recursive calls to function xyz()
```

for eg, if the initial value of *sample_string* is **ABC**, What I want is for each iteration *char_list* will be adding,

`iter 1 - char_list = ['A']`

`iter 2 - char_list = ['A','B']`

`iter 3 - char_list = ['A','B','C']`

Then **sample_string** will become empty and the function will start unrolling:

Now I want to get the list in each iteration in the following order, i.e.,

`char_list = ['A','B','C']`

`char_list = ['A','B']`

`char_list = ['A']`

so that I can do my further operations on the list. I can't use *return* keyword since there are other operations following in the same function including recursive calls to `xyz()`.

The code I wrote is not serving that purpose. For each *unroll*, it is returning the full list (`['A','B','C']`), not in that decrement fashion. I tried the same with a local list variable, still not working. Any idea on how to do this ?

Comment: [Yield](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) keyword may satisfy your needs. It did for me in several recursive occasions.

Comment: Does it have to be recursive? Do you just want to work with a smaller and smaller list on each iteration, in the form of `def f(s): char_list = list(s); while char_list: char_list.pop(); other_processing`?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 took the words right out of my mouth. _Must your function be recursive?_. Don't but arbitrary restrictions and your self, and turn your problem into an [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 It has to recursive. There are a lot of operations to be done only if this part is done.

Comment: I meant in terms of arbitrary project requirements, like a homework assignment intended to test your knowledge of recursion. In terms of only the program itself, recursion is not needed here.

Comment: See, the problem is a bit complex. I question I gave is *not exactly* what I am doing. But something similar. And the second thing is this is the beginning point, I can't proceed further If I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @Rockybilly Can you give some explanation on how to use *yield* in my case ?

Answer (score 0):

```
def xyz(sample_string):
    l = list(sample_string)
    if l :
        for i in reversed(range(1, len(l)+1)):
            print(l[0:i])
```

change the `print` to `yield`, and the function become a generator

what you need is list of number `[1,2,3,4....]`, than you can use `list_[0:i]` to get slice of the `list_`, once you get the list of number, you can reverse it or do something else.
out:

```
['A', 'B', 'C']
['A', 'B']
['A']
```

Comment: The problem is not that simple. It is a bit complex. I need a recursive solution.